# No suitable servers found - when connecting to remote MongoDB Atlas instance from deployed k8s PHP app

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Before I start, I've checked (and tried) every single solution offered already, but still can't get passed the "No suitable servers found" error. Sadly, most SO answers directly relate to local instances, whereas I'm attempting to connect to a **remote** Atlas instance.

I've got a Laravel API, and I'm writing a command to migrate some old data, from MongoDB Atlas instance, into a new structured mysql (locally deployed in k8s) database.

My DSN is: `mongodb+srv://username:encoded_password@cluster_uri.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

And the `handle` code from my command is

```
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $verbose = $this->option('logs');
        $dryRun = $this->option('dryRun');

        $srcModel = strtolower($this->argument('srcModel'));
        $destModel = $this->argument('destModel');

        try {
            $client = new Client(
                Config::get('database.connections.mongodb.dsn'),
                [
                    'serverSelectionTryOnce' => true,
                    'ssl' => false,
                    // Tried with and without this on each and every test
                    // 'authSource' => 'admin',
                ]
            );

            $collection = ($client)
                ->{Config::get('database.connections.mongodb.database')}
                ->{$srcModel};
            $document = $collection->findOne(['_id' => '5e544facbd427b6e9cd9059c']);

            var_dump($document);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            printf($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Initially it wouldn't even connect, until I added google's nameserver to resolv.conf - Now it knows the address, but still never gets passed:

```
kubectl exec -it gateway-api -- php artisan app:migrate-gateway-data -D Tools Tools2
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): 
[Server closed connection. calling hello on 'shard-00-00.uri.mongodb.net:27017']
[Server closed connection. calling hello on 'shard-00-01.uri.mongodb.net:27017']
[Server closed connection. calling hello on 'shard-00-02.uri.mongodb.net:27017']
[Server closed connection. calling hello on 'shard-00-03.uri.mongodb.net:27017']
```

It gets far enough to know what the shards linked are, but no other information is given. Any one have any ideas?

**For sanity, I installed `mongosh` alongside my php image and manually tested connection from the pod command line, with my dsn and that worked. But programmatically it does not**